# Gulp bower:scss not working including bower_components files

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, bower, wiredep

I have an issue with wiredep: In my index.scss file, I have this block at the top:

```
/**
 *  Do not remove this comments bellow. It's the markers used by wiredep to inject
 *  sass dependencies when defined in the bower.json of your dependencies
 */
// bower:scss
// endbower
```

Also, I have installed a bower dependency, let's say `color-dependency`, which contains a couple files *.scss

The problem is that I can't see those files injected in my index.scss

Here is my gulp task for styles

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var _ = require('lodash');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
  var sassOptions = {
    style: 'expanded'
  };

  var injectFiles = gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.scss'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/app/index.scss')
  ], { read: false });

  var injectOptions = {
    transform: function(filePath) {
      filePath = filePath.replace(conf.paths.src + '/app/', '');
      return '@import "' + filePath + '";';
    },
    starttag: '// injector',
    endtag: '// endinjector',
    addRootSlash: false
  };


  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/index.scss')
  ])
    .pipe($.inject(injectFiles, injectOptions))
    .pipe(wiredep(_.extend({}, conf.wiredep)))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass(sassOptions)).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Sass'))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer()).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Autoprefixer'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/')))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem using the gulp generator but only with bootstrap-sass. I added the following to get bootstrap to work:

**conf.js**

```
exports.wiredep = {
  exclude: [/\/bootstrap\.js$/, /\/bootstrap-sass\/.*\.js/, /\/bootstrap\.css/],
  directory: 'bower_components'
};
```

**bower.json**

```
"overrides": {
    "bootstrap-sass": {
      "main": [
        "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"
      ]
    }
  },
```